# TypeError: targetchannel.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Node version : v16.13.1

Discord.js version : 13.3.1

```
TypeError: targetchannel.send is not a function
```

How to fix this Error?

Code:

```
fs.readdir('channels', function (err, files) {
if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
}
files.forEach(function (file) {
    targetchannel = client.channels.fetch(fs.readFileSync('channels/' + file,{encoding:'utf8'}))
    console.log(targetchannel)
    targetchannel.then((value) => {
            targetchannel.send("asdra")
});

});
});
```

log of targetchannel = Promise { < pending > }

image of errors
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixfK5.png

Comment: Log targetchannel when the promise is resolved so log value in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix

I was dumb. The bot called .send before logging in.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
if (!fs.existsSync('channels/')) {
     fs.mkdirSync('channels');
}
fs.readdir('channels', async function (err, files) {
if (err) {
    return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
}
files.forEach(async function (file) {
    targetchannel = await client.channels.fetch(fs.readFileSync('channels/' + file,{encoding:'utf8'}))
    console.log(targetchannel)
    targetchannel.send("asdra")

});
});});
```

Answer (score 0):

"TypeError: <Channel>.send is not a function" means the channel is not correctly defined or was not found.

In your case you need to await since [`<Channel>.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/13.3.1/class/Channel?scrollTo=fetch) is an async method.

```
targetchannel = await client.channels.fetch()
```

Edit: author fixed it and had another problem

Comment: Its showing same error

Comment: Log your `readFileSync` response

Comment: ReadFileSync response is 796993805769244725 a discord channel id
but, client.channels.fetch response is Promise { <pending> }

Comment: I used .then but Its showing same error

Comment: Update your code in your question

Comment: And log targetchannel

Answer (score 0):

`targetChannel` is still the pending promise. Use `value.send()` instead since `value` is the resolved promise

```js
targetchannel.then((value) => {
    value.send("asdra")
})
```